# Hide default error message for a failed robot test

Tags: robotframework

I am writing a robot test to see if a list of servers appears in a unix configuration file.

The test is something along the lines of:

```
Test Case
    @{server_list}=    server1    server2    server3
    ${lines}=    Get File    /etc/config_file
    :FOR    ${server}    in    @{server_list}
    \    Run Keyword and Continue on Failure    Should Contain     ${lines}    ${server}    msg="${server} not in /etc/config_file"
```

When the test fails it prints out my custom error message to console and then prints out the default message, i.e. 'contents of file' does not contain 'server name', to console. The messages also appear in the output.xml file as well.

Is there a way to disable this default message, so that only my custom message is shown?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The msg and values attributes for the Should Contain keyword work like this:

- If msg is not given, the error message is `<first> != <second>`.
- If msg is given and values gets a true value (default), the error message is `<msg>: <first> != <second>`.
- If msg is given and values gets a false value, the error message is simply `<msg>`. See Boolean arguments for more details about using false values.

(see http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20Equal)

So it seems that if you only want your message to be shown you need to set the values=False attribute.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!